# Separate tables vs map lists - DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I need your help. I am quite new to databases.

I'm trying to get set up a table in DynamoDB to store info about TV shows. It seems pretty simple and straightforward but I am not sure if what I am doing is correct.

So far I have this structure. I am trying to fit everything about the TV shows into one table. Seasons and episodes are contained within a list of maps within a list of maps.

Is this too much layering? 
Would this present a problem in the future where some items are huge?
Should I separate some of these lists of maps to another table?

[Shows table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Os0Wq.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you should not put a potentially unbounded list in a single row in DynamoDB because you could end up running into the item size limit of 400kb. Also, if you were to read or write one episode of one show, you consume capacity as if you are reading or writing all the episodes in a show.

Take a look at the [adjacency list pattern](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-adjacency-graphs.html). It’s a good choice because it will allow you to easily find the seasons in a show and the episodes in a season. You can also take a look at [this slide deck](https://www.slideshare.net/mobile/AmazonWebServices/advanced-design-patterns-for-amazon-dynamodb-dat403-reinvent-2017). Part of the way through, it talks about hierarchical data, which is exactly what you’re dealing with.

If you can provide more information about your query patterns, I can give you more guidance on how to model your data in the table.

**Update (2018-11-26)**

Based on your comments, it sounds like you should use composite keys to establish hierarchical 1-N relationships.

By using a composite sort key of `DataType:ItemId` where ItemId is a different format depending on the data type, you have a lot of flexibility.
This approach will allow you to easily get the seasons in the show, get all episodes in *all* seasons, get all episodes in a particular season, or even get all episodes between season 1, episode 5 and season 2 episode 5.

```
hash_key  | sort_key        | data
----------|-----------------|----------------------------
SHOW_1234 | SHOW:SHOW_1234  | {name:"Some TV Show", ...
SHOW_1234 | SEASON:SE_01    | {descr:"In this season, the main character...
SHOW_1234 | EPISODE:S01_E01 | {...
SHOW_1234 | EPISODE:S01_E02 | {...
```

Here are the various key condition expressions for the queries I mentioned:

- `hash_key = "SHOW_1234" and sort_key begins_with("SEASON:")` – gets all seasons
- `hash_key = "SHOW_1234" and sort_key begins_with("EPISODE:")` – gets all episodes in all season
- `hash_key = "SHOW_1234" and sort_key begins_with("EPISODE:S02_")` – gets all episodes in season 2
- `hash_key = "SHOW_1234" and sort_key between "EPISODE:S01_E5" and "EPISODE:S02_E5"` – gets all episodes between season 1, episode 5 and season 2 episode 5

Comment: Hi Matthew, thank you for the reply. 

That makes sense. The table is for a video streaming app. So similar to many others, it lists available shows and when you open a show it shows descriptions, genres, episodes of the currently selected or default season. You change to another season and list episodes of that season etc. Was that what you meant by query patterns?

Comment: Almost. It sounds like your queries are: get all seasons for a show; get all episodes for a season; get a single episode by ID. Anything else?

Comment: Yes. There is a certain feature in the app where some videos are paused at certain times where the user does some interactive activity. And upon completion, the video resumes. So perhaps get pause time(s) for a single episode.

That is basically it.

Comment: What sort of IDs are you using? Do you have UUIDs or some other arbitrary ID for each episode, or are you identifying them by season and episode?

Comment: I trying to do it by season and episode. No IDs.

Comment: So I have been reading up on the adjacency list pattern. If I understand it right, I will have to make an item for every show, season, and episode. Then I have to setup GSI for seasons and episodes where a show can have many seasons, and seasons can have many episodes. Is that the basic idea?

Comment: That's the general idea, except that you only need one GSI, which is essentially a reverse-lookup GSI. You could add other GSIs for other attributes, like a creation date if you want to be able to search by recently added or something. If you don't have unique ids for each episode, then you might want to use hierarchical sort keys instead. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-sort-keys.html

Comment: I am starting to get it, sort of. But I can't seem to set up the GSI correctly.

For a table named Shows, I have ShowTitle as primary key and Season as the sort key. Then I created a secondary index and set the Season as it's primary key and Episode as the sort key. But of course, this would give an error with duplicate keys.

Comment: Just saw your edit. I understand what I need to do now :) thank you!

Comment: The GSI isn’t very useful in your case because you don’t have unique ids for everything, unless you have a burning desire to know how many shows have a second season, or something like that. You can always add a GSI later if you want.

Comment: Also, FYI, a GSI is allowed to have duplicate keys.

Comment: Awesome! I thought that somehow I HAD to do it with GSIs. But it was this simple. I have some experience with relational databases, so I was trying to relate something to something else, I guess. Another thing that I was also worried about was Query vs GetItem. I read that you don't use Queries when you know exactly what you need. So in my case when a user clicks on an episode, I know exactly what show, season and episode. So I can use GetItem to retrieve info about that episode item. And since there is structure in the composite sort key it makes it easy to use GetItem. Would that be correct?

Comment: I know this is old but wouldn't this design cause a hot partition?